# Extracting a string before space and sequence of numbers

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a string that has numbers dash and numbers so it can be

```
1-2
234-45
23-8
```

It can be any sequence of any number up to 12 characters.

These all numbers are preceded by a string. I need to extract this string before this sequence begins.

```
This is a Test1 1-2
This is a test for the first time 234-45
This is a test that is good 23-8
```

so I need to extract

```
This is a Test1

This is a test for the first time 

This is a test that is good
```

there is only one space between this string and the sequence.

Is there any way I can extract that string. Split method is not working here.
I forgot to mention that I have numbers/test before the string too so it can be

```
2123 This is a test for the first time  23-456
```

or

```
 Ac23 This is a test for the first time  23-457
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
var sample = "2123 This is a Test1 1-2";

// Find the first occurrence of a space, and record the position of
// the next letter
var start = sample.IndexOf(' ') + 1; 

// Pull from the string everything starting with the index found above
// to the last space (accounting for the difference from the starting index)
var text = sample.Substring(start, sample.LastIndexOf(' ') - start);
```

After this, `text` should equal:

> This is a Test1

Wrap it up in a nice little function and send your collection of strings through it:

```
string ParseTextFromLine(string input)
{
    var start = input.IndexOf(' ') + 1; 
    return input.Substring(start, input.LastIndexOf(' ') - start);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy,

```
       string s = "This is a Test1 1-2";

       s = s.Substring(0,s.LastIndexOf(" ");
```

and now s will be "This is a Test1"